# 100amp fuse continue braking of Toyota Tercel 99

Tags: toyota, fuse, short, tercel

A 100amp fuse on a Toyota Tercel 1999 broke after a mistake on a new battery polarity. It cut all the lights and the wipers. When I just change it (I changed other fuses too) and started the car, the lights were too brights and the wipers started turning with full speed without activating their switch. Then the fuse just broke again.
It seems there is a short somewhere but I couldn't find it.

Comment: What you describe, such as wipers starting etc suggest that there is other damage - control modules or wiring even. You need to investigate what is happening logically - do the wipers continue if their fuse is removed for example?

Comment: I don't know because the 100amp fuse is no broken, so there is no lights, no wipers. I tried to check all the wiring but it's very difficult to remove the interior plastic board. What does the ctr module look like?

Comment: you will likely need a service manual with full wiring diagrams to start diagnosing this.